# Extracting variables from multi line response in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I want to extract certain text from the response i get in jMeter but the issue is that the response is multiline and does not extract the value correctly. I have tried using multiline mode which got me somewhere but not fully.
Here is the response:

```
                "category61B" : [ "Specified Insurance Company",
                    "Investment Entity", "Custodial Institution ",
                    "Depository Institution", "Other" ],
```

I want to extract every value inside the square brackets without ".
Regex i wrote for this is:

> (?s)\"category61B\" : [ \"([^"]+)\"
>   which gave me:
>
> Specified Insurance Company

I am not able to write further regex to get the other values.

Note: I tried [online Regex Tester](https://regex101.com/r/CK3ybH/1/) and it gave me the correct groups. Obviously i tried the same regex with jmeter and it gave me 0 matches but no errors.

The regex  wrote there was:

```
(?s)\"category61B\" : \[ \"(.+?)\",\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\"(.+?)\", \"(.+?)\",\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\"(.+?)\", \"(.+?)\" ],
```

Update:
I tried the below RegEx but this will result in capturing everything till the end of response.

```
(?s)"category61B".*\[(.*)\]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try out: `(?s)"category61B".*\[(.*)\]`, looking into [RegExp Tester mode of the View Results Tree listener](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script) it should be something you're looking for

[image: JMeter View Results Tree RegExp Tester]

---

By the way, your response is utterly like to be a [JSON](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_intro.asp) structure so my expectation is that using [JSON Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) will much easier and as simple as `$..category61B`

Comment: Obligatory link to [Regular Expressions: Now you have two problems](https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/)

Comment: @Dmitri - Sorry but i forgot to mention this. I had already tried this but the issue with not using '?' is that it will capture everything till the end of the response which is a lot in this case. I have updated my question with this info.

Answer (score 0):

@MitSM

I have worked on query, you have posted.Please go through the details below hope it serves the purpose.

Regex I wrote in Jmeter and executed was:

```
(?m)"category61B" : \[ "(.*)\"\,\n                    "(.*)\"\, "(.*)\"\,\n                    "(.*)"\, "(.*)" \]\,
```

1. Also, I have validated the another regex on regex101,which is :

   (?m)"category61B" : [ "(.*)\"\,\n \s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s"(.*)\"\, "(.*)\"\,\n \s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s"(.*)"\, "(.*)" ]\,

   Please find attached:"Regex_1"

[image: Regex_1]

2. I have also executed it on Jmeter using jp@gc - Dummy Sampler and response you have provided.Refer post execution result :"Result" and you can utilize individual groups viz. categoryId_g1,categoryId_g2,categoryId_g3 etc. for every value inside the square brackets without ".

[image: Result]